# Nested vectors in a function that is applied to dataframe in R

Tags: r, function, dataframe, apply

I have the basic data below (dput provided at the end of the question):

```
P <- 72
E_c <- 80000
head (deflections)
    L   I_comp
1  60 17299.21
2  70 25760.94
3  80 32734.69
4  90 51343.59
5 100 60167.30
6 110 64887.87
```

I want to find the maximum deflection, using the equation:
[image]

Where `b` is defined as `b = L - a` and `a` is a vector that can be defined as

```
a <- seq(10,L,10)
```

and `x` is a nested sequence whitin `a` such that

```
x <- seq(1,a,1)
```

I have written the function below to calculate the maximum deflection delta at all `x` values for all `a` values.

```
delta_less <- function(x){
  a_seq <- seq(10,L,10)
  L <- x[1]
  I_comp <- x[2]
  X_seq <- seq(a_seq)
  delta <- ((P*(L-a_seq)*X_seq)/(6*E_c*I_comp*L))*(L^2-(L-a_seq)^2-X_seq^2)
  c(val = max(delta), pos = which.max(delta))
}

test <- cbind(deflections, vars = t(apply(deflections,1,delta_less)))
```

The problem is that my code is not recognizing the nested sequence. It only works if I give `a_seq` a singular numerical value.

Data provided:

```
dput(deflections)
structure(list(L = c(60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 110, 120, 130, 140, 
60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 110, 120, 130, 140, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 
110, 120, 130, 140, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 110, 120, 130, 140), 
    I_comp = c(17299.2063000114, 25760.9420686703, 32734.6949444858, 
    51343.5889683982, 60167.3001695375, 64887.8729936444, 83451.9473750139, 
    103000.852590734, 112631.744898846, 23539.3443398425, 23544.8558575609, 
    32808.739059987, 40880.4964809276, 60171.1172692296, 64894.6680546358, 
    83469.4777437875, 103114.132264558, 120223.534252571, 23539.3443398425, 
    25772.7904955165, 32810.8231970971, 51345.5936366056, 74673.7079705815, 
    80752.3694583712, 103114.132264558, 103114.132264558, 147386.853127916, 
    23539.3443398425, 25767.8092758621, 40881.3376639665, 55608.9342154021, 
    80694.6568665257, 80752.3694583712, 119068.355471205, 119402.817753462, 
    147386.853127916)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-36L))
```

Comment: Since `a_seq` depends on `L` it should be assigned after `L` in function. Doing so, I get no issues with your code: https://rextester.com/TGZPB48909

Comment: @Parfait I know it is not giving an error but the answer is not correct either. If I manually change `a_seq` to 40 (which is a value it should be able to go through) the pos column changes.

Comment: Please post desired results for a few rows.